# Is any homogeneous Sobolev space $\dot{W}^{s,p}$ a "homogeneous Banach space", as the the name suggests?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, besov-space

A homoegeneous Sobolev space $\dot{W}^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is defined to be the completion of the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ under the norm
\begin{equation}
\lVert (-\Delta)^{s/2} f \rVert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}
\end{equation}
Here $s>0, p \geq 1$.

Now, I wonder if "any" $\dot{W}^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a "homogeneous Banach space", in the sense that it is linearly homeomorphic to all its infinite dimensioanl subspaces. I think the name suggests it, but cannot find any relevant proof.

Also, instead of $\mathbb{R}^n$, can we think of a compact manifold like $\mathbb{T}^n:=[\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}]^n$ and still get the same result?

That is, if we define $\dot{W}^{s,p}(\mathbb{T}^n)$ as the completion of the $\{ f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^n) \mid \int_{\mathbb{T}^n} f=0\}$ under the above norm, is $\dot{W}^{s,p}(\mathbb{T}^n)$ still a homogeneous Banach space?

Could anyone please clarfiy for me, or provide any reference?

Comment: I’m not sure if it’s a homogeneous Banach space, but the “homogeneous” in ‘homogeneous Sobolev space’ comes from the PDE language, particularly the fact that after taking Fourier transforms, it’s like multiplying $|\xi|^s$, which is a degree $s$ homogeneous polynomial in $\xi$ (replacing $\xi$ by $t\xi$ brings out a power of $t^s$). As opposed to multiplying by the full $(1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2}$ ($|\xi|^s$ is the ‘top order homogeneous part’). So, if you’re trying to connect the concepts merely due to the same terminology, you might be disappointed.

Comment: Another comment: one should take care about taking completion to define homogeneous Sobolev spaces. Indeed, one need an abstract ambiant structure to make sure the completion makes sense, and that all those completions can "talk with eachother" somehow. One usually uses $\mathcal{S}'/\mathcal{P}$: tempered distributions quotiented by polynomials.

In fact, one can prove that $\dot{\mathrm{H}}^\frac{n}{2}$ cannot be embedded in $\mathcal{D}'$, i.e. such completion CANNOT made of distributions (in particular, the elements cannot be tempered distributions) so $\mathcal{D}'$ does not fit.